# QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, method, stuff+params) vs object->method()

Tags: c++, qt

What I have is these two calls to a method in another object in another thread.

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "method", Qt::variousOptionalParameters,
          Q_ARG(int, a), Q_ARG(int, b), Q_ARG(float, c), Q_ARG(QString, d));
```

and

```
object->method(a, b, c,  d);
```

They do exactly the same thing (in this case, at least, where they update some GUI elements, and also the region of interest for OpenCV thread). What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 8):

`QObject` and derived can have thread affinity, and if they do, you can schedule queued calls to its methods. This can be useful as an easy synchronization where performance is not critical, obviously, you won't be using queued connections in a tight loop, because you will get **massive performance penalty**.

Just like `deleteLater()`, queued calls are useful when you want the call to occur "in the clean", in between event loop iterations, to minimize the possible side effects of other ongoing operations, when you don't want anything else running that may have a side effect on the queued operation, or you want everything that was intended to affect the operation to have been executed. Also, in the case of deletion, this will remove any pending events, connections and whatnot.

The direct call will be that much faster, but you don't have the safety. In most cases you could be fine, which will make an eventual problem that much harder to pinpoint.

If you plan on doing that between different threads, you must implement your own synchronization, for example a `QMutex` and make sure all access to that object passes through it. It will be a lot faster than using queued connections.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, "Qt::QueuedConnection" means it is a queued connection, meant for inter-thread communication

```
// works across thread, the data is cached internally by Qt, 
// passed down to the receiving thread once it resumes
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "method", Qt::QueuedConnection,
Q_ARG(int, a), Q_ARG(int, b), Q_ARG(float, c), Q_ARG(QString, d));
```

In the other case, it is a direct call

```
object->method(a, b, c,  d); // object should be within the same thread
```

You could also achieve it using Qt::connect, where Qt automatically determines whether the *type* parameter should be queued or direct and can be overridden by the programmer

```
connect(const QObject * sender, const char * signal, const char * method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection) const
```

Please read the description of connection type [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

**Qt::QueuedConnection**

*The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.*

Comment: In the second Should be in the same thread or HAS to be? Because that call works, and the object is in a different thread.  Also, "Qt::QueuedConnection" is just an optional parameter

Comment: @Petersaber - it is optional, but Qt will check for thread affinity, and use it anyway in the case of leaving the default value, which is auto connection.

Comment: @Petersaber - also, it doesn't HAVE to be, but it should be, otherwise you MAY run into problems depending on what you do.

Comment: threading issues are very subtle to debug, the second one works perhaps this time but may not work next time, hence I would second @ddriver, the call should be serialized